# "classList.toggle" doesn't work for buttons

Tags: javascript, html, css, dom

I've been creating a website and I have made a night mode for it. Night Mode works fine for everything except buttons. How can I fix this problem?

HTML:

```
<section class="form" id="contact">
    <div class="form-main">
        <form>              
        <button type="button" id="pay">
            <p class="p">Proceed To Pay</p> 
        </button>       
    </form>
    </div>
</section>
```

CSS:

```
.darkTheme{
background-color: #000;
color: #fff;
transition: all 0.3s;}
```

JS:

```
let payBtn = document.querySelector('.p');
btn.addEventListener('click' , changeBg);

function changeBg(){
    console.log(payBtn);
    payBtn.classList.add('darkTheme');
}
```

Comment: I think you are setting the bacground-color for the p element in the button. Instead you should set the background-color for the button.

Comment: I first tried that way but it didn't work. Tried again now too but still not working

Comment: @Ajax, Change ```document.querySelector('.p');``` to  ```document.querySelector('#pay');``` .. https://codepen.io/Maniraj_Murugan/pen/WNGEWWR

Comment: Also ```btn.addEventListener``` needs to be  ```payBtn.addEventListener``` ..

Comment: As i said, you are changing the bg of p not button. check out my answer. I only changed that thing and it works fine.

Answer (score 3):

After many attempts I found a way to fix the problem but it's kind of a long journey. First I wanted to use "classList.toggle" for the class that was in CSS. Since it didn't work as I wanted, I selected the button with Id;

```
let pay = document.getElementById('pay');
```

Then instead of using "classList.toggle" for the class in CSS I used conditional statements to get the same result I wanted.

```
if(pay.classList.contains('hello')){
    pay.classList.remove('hello');
    pay.style.backgroundColor = "#000";
    pay.style.color = "#fff";
}else{
    pay.style.backgroundColor = "#fff";
    pay.style.color = "#000";
    pay.className = "hello";
}
```

So I made 'hello' class to get the toggle effect and used style to get the desired output.
Finally it worked.
Here the full project hosted on codepen: https://codepen.io/kisaraf/pen/vYXJwLE
Thank You for everyone who tried to help me.

Comment: And whatever you added in your answer, i provided that in mine. The only thing was that i was applying the changes on buttons only. I think you just copy pasted my code to check and didn't checked what i have written in it.

Comment: I didn't just copy pastesd. I made the necessary changes and matched them accordingly as well.

Comment: But you can run my program and that works perfectly.

Answer (score 1):

```js
let payBtn = document.querySelectorAll('button');
document.getElementById("dm").addEventListener('click', function() {
           payBtn.forEach(function(btn) {
        if(!btn.classList.contains('darkTheme')) {
            btn.classList.add('darkTheme');
            document.getElementById('dt-text').innerHTML = 'change to light';
        }else {
            btn.classList.remove('darkTheme');
            document.getElementById('dt-text').innerHTML = 'change to dark';
        }
       
    });
});
```

```css
.darkTheme{
background-color: #000;
color: #fff;
transition: all 0.3s;}
```

```html
<section class="form" id="contact">
    <div class="form-main">
        <form>              
        <button type="button">
            <p class="p">Proceed To Pay</p> 
        </button> 
        <button type="button">
            <p class="p">Proceed To Pay 2</p> 
        </button> 
        <button type="button">
            <p class="p">Proceed To Pay 3</p> 
        </button> 
        <button type="button" id="dm"><p id='dt-text'>change to dark</p></button>     
    </form>
    </div>
</section>
```

Instead of selecting the paragraph element inside the button, select the button.

Comment: Sorry I forgot to mention that I'm clicking another button which makes whole page goes night mode. I only has this problem with the buttons not other elements.

Comment: Please stay a second. i will edit my answer as per your question.

Comment: https://codepen.io/kisaraf/pen/vYXJwLE This is the link for the code pen

Comment: Check my answer. Works completely as you wanted. On clicking the last button, you can see all the other buttons change to dark theme.

Comment: It needs to be toggled mate

Comment: I edited my answer. Now i think this is all what you want. The button now shifts from the modes(dark and light).

Comment: I tried again but still couldn't get result. But I found a way, bit long but did work. See my answer. Thank You for your time mate

Comment: This is working completely fine. As you wanted, i added a toggle button. I only added the functionality of changing the mode of buttons not the whole page because you were already doing that well as you said, but your problem was only related with the buttons.

Answer (score 1):

Check this out. You'll be able to easily toggle between the dark theme and the normal theme with this approach.

```js
let payBtn = document.querySelector("#pay");
payBtn.addEventListener("click", changeBg);

function changeBg() {
  console.log(payBtn);
  payBtn.classList.toggle("darkTheme");
}
```

```css
.darkTheme {
  background-color: #000;
  color: #fff;
  transition: all 0.3s;
}
```

```html
<section class="form" id="contact">
  <div class="form-main">
    <form>
      <button type="button" id="pay">
        <p class="p">Proceed To Pay</p>
      </button>
    </form>
  </div>
</section>
```

Answer (score 0):

**html**

```
<section class="form" id="contact">
    <div class="form-main">
        <form>              
        <button type="button" id="pay">
            <p class="p">Proceed To Pay</p> 
        </button>       
    </form>
    </div>
</section>
```

**css**

```
.darkTheme{
background-color: #000;
color: #fff;
transition: all 0.3s;}
```

**js**

```
let payBtn = document.querySelector('button');
payBtn.addEventListener('click' , changeBg);

function changeBg(){
    console.log(payBtn);
    payBtn.classList.toggle('darkTheme');
}
```